# Изменяется размер figure

Tags: html, css

Код:

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

figure img {
  border: none;
  background-color: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

figure figcaption {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg/300px-Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg"></p>
  <figcaption>Mountain Everest - the biggest mountain. 8850 meters above sea level</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Почему текст не переходит на новую строку, а изменяет рaзмер figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Встречный вопрос — а почему он должен переноситься? Размер всплывающего блока напрямую зависит от контента, если не задан явно. У вас есть несколько вариантов.

1:

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  max-width: 300px;
}

figure img {
  border: none;
  background-color: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

figure figcaption {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg/300px-Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg"></p>
  <figcaption>Mountain Everest - the biggest mountain. 8850 meters above sea level</figcaption>
</figure>
```

2:

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

figure img {
  border: none;
  background-color: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

figure figcaption {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg/300px-Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg"></p>
  <figcaption>Mountain Everest - the biggest mountain. 8850 meters above sea level</figcaption>
</figure>
```

3 (поддержка `width: min-content` пока не на высоте):

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: min-content;
}

figure img {
  border: none;
  background-color: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

figure figcaption {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg/300px-Everest_North_Face_toward_Base_Camp_Tibet_Luca_Galuzzi_2006.jpg"></p>
  <figcaption>Mountain Everest - the biggest mountain. 8850 meters above sea level</figcaption>
</figure>
```